# How to fill empty fields when I save form from POST

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I try to fill empty fields when I save model form, but unfortunately, it doesn't work properly.

this is my view:

```
     def bylaw_save(request):
        form = BylawForm(initial={'who_created': request.user.username})
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BylawForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                gdn = GlobalDocNumber.objects.get(pk=1)
                gdn.gdn += 1
                gdn.save()
                raspr_num = form.cleaned_data['raspr_num'][:]
                raspr_num = raspr_num.split('/')
                bylaw = form.save(commit=False)
                bylaw.district = 'unfilled'
                bylaw.department = 'unfilled'
                bylaw.performer = 'unfilled'
                bylaw.check_type = 'unfilled'
                bylaw.save()
                return bylaw_form(request, msg='test')
            else:
                return bylaw_form(request, msg='test')
        return render(request, 'bylaw/bylaw_form.html', {'form': form})
```

this is fraction of my form:

```
district = ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=DistrictsMenu.objects.all(), to_field_name="district",
                            widget=Select(attrs={'id': "district", 'class': 'form-control col-6'}))

department = ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=DepartmentsMenu.objects.all(), to_field_name="department",
                              widget=Select(attrs={'id':"department", 'class': "form-control col-6"}))
```

UPDATE: This is my model with default='Unfilled', according to Arthur M and  Rohan suggestions (But it also doesn't work, it gives me a "NOT NULL constraint failed: bylaw_bylawmodel.department" error, in this case I don't fill department field):

```
class BylawModel(models.Model):

    raspr_date = models.DateField()
    district = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Unfilled')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Unfilled')
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Unfilled')
    inn = models.IntegerField()
    performer = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Unfilled')
    check_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_proved = models.DateField()
    raspr_num = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    who_created = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

when I save this from, it always fills with 'unfilled'. How can I fill empty values only if they are really empty?

Comment: post the model for this modelform

Comment: You can use `defaul='unfilled'` in model definition for these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing 
`bylaw.fieldName = 'unfilled'` you're overwriting the value sent from your form.

If you don't want to add a default value in your model (which I would recommend) you can add a simple :

```
if not bylaw.fieldName:
  bylaw.fieldName = 'unfilled'
```

For every one of your fields.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but I have a error when I set default model value. btw, another version with "if not" works fine!

Comment: If you set a default value in your model and the attribute hasn't been set, `form.is_valid()` will return `False` ... For it to work, you need to set the field to be nullable in your model.
If you used my suggestion ("if not..." thanks for validating my answer).
If not, thanks for sharing the final solution editing your post.